# Vue.js 2 datepicker recommendation?

Tags: vue.js

I'm looking for recommendations for a Vue.js 2.0 date picker component. My requirements are fairly simple.

1. Should have option to pick a range - start date, end date.
2. Should be stylable.
3. Should be able to trigger a method when a date is selected.

I've been using https://github.com/charliekassel/vuejs-datepicker so far, which is good but doesn't have the range option (unless I've missed it). This one looks promising - https://github.com/mengxiong10/vue2-datepicker - but I don't immediately see how I can trigger a method when a date is selected.

Answer (score 9):

There is a component family called [Element](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US), here is the [DatePicker](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/date-picker). You can import only the DatePicker if you want (Check the "On demand" part [here](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/quickstart)).

It supports range selection (`type="daterange"`).

There is also at least two ways to catch the selection event. It has a `change` event, and also with the `picker-options` prop you can pass an `onPick` callback.

I am not sure about the custom styling, as I can see there is a way to give a custom class for the dropdown with the `popper-class` prop but I am not sure how that works.

Comment: Thanks for the link to Element awsome

Comment: Anyone who figures out the popper-class thing, I would sure like to know.